# How to register an interface and an implementation class in SpringBoot (no xml, no annotation)?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm from .NET.

I have an interface `UserService` and an implementation class `UserServiceImpl`.
I want to use some code like below

```
beanFactory.register<UserService, UserServiceImpl>(Scope.Request);
```

I dont' want to use annotation or XML config file. 
Can anyone help me translate it to java code using SpringBoot?

==update==

What I'm trying to do is to make my own classes pure java code without depending on any framework jar.

Comment: Use a configuration class.

Comment: Can you show some code please:)

Comment: `@Bean public UserServiceImpl() return new UserServiceImpl();`. I strongly suggest a read of the Spring documentation on how to do configuration.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a solution without using annotation? I don't want the `UserServiceImpl` class to be coupled with Spring framework.

Comment: It isn't coupled, there is only a spring specific config class, it doesn't change your userserviceimpl.

Comment: How is `beanFactory.register` NOT depending on a framework jar. You need either xml or java config to register yur bean without modifying the bean itself.

Comment: you can register beandefinition with void registerBeanDefinition(String beanName, BeanDefinition beanDefinition) https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/bean-definition.html

Comment: @M. Deinum what I mean is that `UserServiceImpl ` lives in my `business.jar` lib which will not depend on Spring framework. `business.jar` lib is designed to be used in any java applications, e.g. java swing desktop application. The code `beanFactory.register` is in my web application, of course, the web application depends on Spring framework. But I wish   `business.jarl` lib don't.

Comment: @Devilluminati thanks for the link, it's very helpful.

Comment: And why do you think the configuration class needs to be in your `business.jar` that can be perfectly fine part of your web app. Just create a configuration class in your web app where you construct the services you need. That is also the point where you know what you need. Or you could even use component scanning with a special include filter for the services you want (you don't need to use `@Component`). And finally you could even use java standard annotations from CDI to construct Spring components then you only have default annotations and no framework specific ones.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you for your reply. `@Bean public UserServiceImpl() return new UserServiceImpl();` actually does not fulfill my need. The class `UserServiceImpl` has a lot of dependencies and I don't want to new it by myself. Also, I don't want component scanning because I want to register components explicitly in code. By far, I have found a solution: use the `DefaultListableBeanFactory` to do registration programmatically. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You can inject the dependencies as method arguments. But if you want to do the cumbersome work of instead of using Java Config to manually define all the bean definitions (which will probably fail as you are probably doing that too late in the process) be my guest. Even with a bean-definition you will need to register the dependencies and define them as constructor arguments/setters. Looks like you want the hard way.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes, it's harder. But I do want to depend on Spring framework as less as possible. I believe annotations (which are hidden dependencies) are used too much by Spring.

Comment: So instead of relying on meta-information (which will make your code less dependend) you want to use a path that no one uses and heavily relies on internal stuff from within Spring? You are basically reinventing the wheel by going along that path.